# How can I encode wav to mp3 in dolphin from contextmenu on Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, dolphin

I have a Music folder with lots of wav files. Is it possible to get a rightclick menu for wav files to encode them into mp3 or flac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the **KDE service menus** manually on Xubuntu:

- [download kde-services](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/kde-services?content=147065)  to `/tmp`
- install:

  ```
  cd /tmp

  tar xf kde-services*.tar.bz2

  cd kde-services-1.9

  make

  sudo make install
  ```

This will add

> multimedia tools: [extract|convert] audio track

to folders in dolphin that are containing media files

Answer (score 0):

**KDE context/service menus**

The Dolphin /1,2/ is a KDE file manager. As a KDE application it is using the KDE service menus /3/.

**Right click audio conversion menu with the Dolphin**

One option is to install the soundKonverter /4/. It is in the Ubuntu repositories /5/:

```
:~$ apt-cache show soundkonverter
Package: soundkonverter
Priority: optional
Section: universe/kde
...
Description: audio converter frontend for KDE
 soundKonverter is a frontend to various audio converters.
 .
 The key features are:
  - Audio conversion
  - Replay Gain calculation
  - CD ripping
 .
 soundKonverter supports reading and writing tags for many formats, so the tags
 are preserved when converting files.
 .
 See README.Debian for more information on supported formats.

Homepage: http://www.kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=29024
```

It will add the 'Convert with soundKonverter' context menu.

[image]

**Links**

1. http://dolphin.kde.org/
2. http://www.kde.org/applications/system/dolphin/
3. http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Creating_Konqueror_Service_Menus
4. http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/soundKonverter?content=29024
5. http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=soundkonverter&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Comment: `apt-get install soundkonverter` installs it too. You get the option in the dolphin menu on Xubuntu after a while (I restarted dolphin and went into the "Dienste" menu in settings twice until it appeared though)

Comment: This doesn't seem to add any context menu in dolphin on Ubuntus unity desktop. (I use 14.04)